# How to change background colour of frame in 3b1bmanim?

Tags: manim

I downloaded latest version of 3b1b manim from github. When I render the scenes by default background is gray how to change it to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `manim-master` folder open `custom defaults.yml`  change bgcolor from #33333 to #00000